# Mysql: operator error runs in phpmyadmin but not in php

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following

```
select p.*, (select paypal_status from tbl_order as o where paypal_status = 'paid' and end_time > now() and p.post_id = o.post_id) as sort_post  from tbl_postad as p where post_category in ('1','7','14','20','26','32','38','44','50','56','62','68','74','80','97','140','144','150','177','179','235','259','284','298','334','370','397','410','429','450','467','479','495','522','535','543') and post_expiredate >= '2018-07-25 13:00:18' and post_delete_status!='Y' and post_cat_status!='N' and block = 0  and post_country = "India"  and post_status = 'Y' order by post_date desc LIMIT 0, 15
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'post_category in
>   ('1','7','14','20','26','32','38','44','50','56','62','68','74'' at
>   line 1

The query executes correctly in phpmyadmin:

```
select p.*, (select paypal_status from tbl_order as o where paypal_status = 'paid' and end_time > now() and p.post_id = o.post_id) as sort_post  from tbl_postad as p where post_category in ('1','7','14','20','26','32','38','44','50','56','62','68','74','80','97','140','144','150','177','179','235','259','284','298','334','370','397','410','429','450','467','479','495','522','535','543') and post_expiredate >= '2018-07-25 13:00:18' and post_delete_status!='Y' and post_cat_status!='N' and block = 0  and post_country = "India"  and post_status = 'Y' order by post_date desc LIMIT 0, 15
```

Even the shortest query returns error:

```
select p.*, (select paypal_status from tbl_order as o where paypal_status = 'paid' and end_time > now() and p.post_id = o.post_id) as sort_post  from tbl_postad as p where post_status='Y' order by post_date desc LIMIT 0, 15
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'post_status='Y'' at line 1

My PHP version: PHP Version 5.6.36

Comment: I also check sql execute..but try to alias all where condition with p. than try and also one thing while aliasing table "as" is not needed.

Comment: @Kandy but the query runs fine in phpmyadmin

Comment: ya i also tried and success. can you tell me your PHP version

Comment: @Kandy  PHP Version 5.6.36

Comment: Can you post your PHP code?

Comment: I didn't written any PHP code . I just try in phpmyadmin. Remove "as" in aliasing table than try with php